# Dump TEB/PEB in immunitydbg

Tags: windows, immunity-debugger, operating-systems

I am trying to learn actually how to get to the PEB inside of TEB. I have tried this with `windbg` but could not manage to dump the PEB with stuff like:

```
!peb
```

or

```
dt nt!_PEB_LDR_DATA
```

And others. But, I could not manage to get the PEB dumped. So also my favorite debugger is still `immunitydbg`. So, I was trying to get to the information using `immunitydbg` CLI. But the nearest thing I have managed to get to PEB is dumping the TEB.

```
d fs:[0]
```

So, I there anyhow someway inside of immunity do get the contents of TEB/PEB? I also tried to use the `Ollysdbg` PE Dump plugin but that only gave me another exe file with different contents. And also i am not sure if the PE Plugin does the right thing for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the Memory Map window in OllyDbg/ImmunityDbg, scroll down to the bottom, and double click on the entry that contains `Process Environment Block`. This will open a dump of the PEB in OllyDbg/ImmunityDbg:

[image: PEB]

Comment: i have tied that but i could not manage to find the Entry which contains "Process Environment Block" there is no such line when i open $application inside of OllyDbg/ImmunityDbg :\ . But i found some plugin called mona which also solves my problem. Being capable But doing this by hand would be much more awesome.

Comment: ImmunityDbg is terribly outdated. What version of OllyDbg did you test this on?

Comment: The one i used at home was v1.10

Comment: OllyDbg v1.10 is 10 years old. Please try with OllyDbg v2.01 - http://www.ollydbg.de/version2.html

Answer (score 3):

```
alt + f1 d fs:[30] ollydbg 1.10  raw peb
```

with `stolly plugin` for 1.10 `select the first byte` in `dump->right click->sructure` 
`select _peb`  from drop down box for decoded peb .

```
al+g fs:[30] in ollydbg 2.01 fully decoded _peb in dump / disasm window
```